# Problem with Boehm gc and mutli-thread program

Tags: c, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have a problem when using the `Boehm`garbage collector in a multi-thread program.
My main function sleeps, while a thread is performing some allocations and deallocations using the garbage collector.

When a `collect()` is called by the garbage collector, the sleep of the main thread is interrupted, and the program continues as if nothing happened.

The following source code terminates in 1 second while it must sleep at least 100 seconds :

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GC_THREADS
#include <gc/gc.h>

void foo () {
    sleep (1);
    GC_gcollect (); // or multiple allocation, that will trigger a collect at some point
}

void * thread_func (void* data) {
    foo ();
}

int main () {
    // GC_init (); ordinarily useless, and does not change anything 
    pthread_t id;
    GC_pthread_create (&id, NULL, &thread_func, NULL);
    sleep (100);
    printf ("End \n");
}
```

The same problem happens, when that is the thread, which is sleeping and the main function that performs the allocations.
I am using the last stable version of `bohem gc` (namely the `8.0.4`), on `ubuntu-18.04`.

Does someone have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: I bet sleep returns the error code EINTR.

Comment: @Emile Cadorel - Do you rather mean "Boehm GC"?

Comment: I think you should actually call GC_init() if you are compiling with a C compiler and not a C++ compiler. But I don't understand why sleep() doesn't work. What does sleep() return?

Comment: Yes sorry Boehm GC. 
The function returns the value `98`, so not EINTR, which is equal to `4`. 
`98` is the value of `EADDRINUSE` in errno.h

Comment: `sleep()` returns `98`, and errno is set to `4`

Comment: Ah, ok you are right, interesting thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector uses a number of signals (According to the [debugging documentation](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/debugging.html), `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, and also `SIGPWR` and `SIGXCPU` on multithreaded linux setups like you're using) internally, and sets signal handler functions for them.

`sleep()` will be interrupted when a signal handler is called, and returns the number of seconds remaining before it would have timed out if not interrupted. This will happen if a collection is triggered in mid-sleep.

So, if you want to mix `sleep()` with the garbage collector, you'd have to use a loop like:

```
int timeout = 100;
int time_remaining;
while ((time_remaining = sleep(timeout)) > 0) {
  timeout = time_remaining;
}
```

A more robust implementation uses [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) directly (It's how `sleep()` is implemented on Linux+Glibc) for better error handling:

```
struct timespec req = { .tv_sec = 100, .tv_nsec = 0 };
struct timespec rem;
while (nanosleep(&req, &rem) < 0) {
  if (errno == EINTR) {
    // Interrupted by a signal handler
    req = rem;
  } else {
    // Some other error happened; handle appropriately for your application
    perror("nanosleep");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

---

An even more robust version, that won't sleep for longer than 100 seconds because of time used by the garbage collector (Unless time spent sleeping so far + gc time goes over that) uses [`clock_nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html) to sleep until after a given timestamp:

```
struct timespec req;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &req) < 0) {
  perror("clock_gettime");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
req.tv_sec += 100;
int rc;
while ((rc = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &req, NULL)) != 0) {
  if (rc != EINTR) {
     fprintf(stderr, "clock_nanosleep: %s\n", strerror(rc));
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```